# How to upload image(svg file) to firestore Nuxt

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

Code:

```
export default {
  name: 'IndexPage',
  data() {
    return {
      image: null,
      heroTitle: '',
      heroSubtitle: '',
    }
  },

  methods: {

    async postData() {
      try {
        await this.$fire.firestore.collection('heroPage').doc('admin').set({
          heroTitle: this.heroTitle,
          heroSubtitle: this.heroSubtitle,
          heroImage: this.image,
        })
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    },
  },
}
```

Error:

FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom File object (found in field heroImage in document heroPage/admin)

Comment: You cannot upload an image to Firestore. I would suggest use Firebase storage instead.

Comment: True, firestore is a mongo-like DB.

Comment: You mean, realtime database of firebase? @kissu

Comment: It's in the name: database. Not meant for assets like images.